# Running a page in a different port in web server in Grails

Tags: java, grails, web, port

I am running the grails application in a port 9200 and I have a healthcheck url and the link is http://myapp:9200/healthcheck.
I want to run the healthcheck alone in a different port number, for example http://myapp:9300/healthcheck, is there a way to do in grails ?
The reason is I want to abstract the health check URL from users.

Comment: how do you start your app ? if you start with grails-app command you can add -Dserver.port=9300 as argument

Comment: Is there a way  that the single page can be in a different port

Comment: no the whole application runs on a specific part. not sure what you mean by abstract url from users, but if you have part of application that should not reach users, you can secure this part (and this part only) if they should not have access or just not referencing the link so your users would not access it